# Почему коммиты не показываются в contributions graph в github?

Tags: github

Знающие профессионалы, подскажите пожалуйста, почему в сетке contributions graph в github не показываются коммиты?
Пример: https://github.com/skaffman41/tasksmvprxjava/commits/master   Есть коммиты от 22 и 23 июня. Но в сетке в этой, где квадраты разноцветные никакой активности в эти дни типа не было https://github.com/skaffman41 ... Как быть? Заранее благодарю.

Comment: github считает статистику по указанному email. У коммитов он либо не указан, либо указан, но не привязан к вашему аккаунту.

Comment: Странно. А как это проверить, не подскажете? Ведь в проекте эти коммиты видны.

Comment: Monk, большое вам спасибо, разобрался.

Comment: Эпичный ответ =) автор разобрался, но не сказал как